# Listen to incoming multipart SMS message

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, multipart

I can catch newly incoming SMS messages. But if that is a multipart message, my broadcast receiver receives all parts of the message at several times.

Is there a way to receive the whole message at one time - like default messaging app does?

Comment: How do you know that the default messaging app receives the entire message at once? I would guess it receives them separately and then combines them internally.

Comment: @slayton Thanks. So I think I can compare datetime and combine all parts into one. Do you think that there is a flag somewhere -- which indicates that this message is a piece of a large message?

Comment: I don't know but you can always look at the Android sources and see how they do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holy...!

After reading the Android source ([this file](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_mms/blob/master/src/com/android/mms/transaction/SmsReceiverService.java)), I realize that this is such a stupid question...

Here is my receiver:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d(ClassName, "received SMS");

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        // here is what I need, just combine them all  :-)
        final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        Log.d(ClassName, String.format("message count = %s", messages.length));
        for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
            messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        }
    }
}// onReceive()
```

Oops... I was too lazy to look at my code. I already got all parts of the message at a time.

Comment: Please check the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469881/broadcastreceiver-for-multipart-sms
Each intent contains a single message including all its parts together. It is easy