# Permissions policy that will limit which apps are allowed to request Call Log and SMS permissions

Tags: android, google-play-services

Today I got a mail like this, according to this I’m not able to use `RECEIVE_SMS READ_SMS` anymore in my app. In my app I’m using auto read OTP. Is there any solution for this?

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> In October, we announced updates to our Permissions policy that will
>   limit which apps are allowed to request Call Log and SMS permissions.
>   This policy will impact one or more of your apps.
>
> Only an app that has been selected as a user's default app for making
>   calls or text messages, or whose core functionality is approved for
>   one of the exception use cases, will be able to request access to Call
>   Log or SMS permissions.
>
> Action required
>
> Below, we've listed apps from your catalog which do not meet the
>   requirements for permission requests. Please remove any disallowed or
>   unused permissions from your app's manifest (specified below), migrate
>   to an alternative implementation (e.g. SMS Retriever API for most
>   cases of OTP verification), or evaluate if your app qualifies for an
>   exception.
>
> Next steps
>
> Read through the Permissions policy and the Play Console Help Center
>   article, which describes intended uses, exceptions, invalid uses, and
>   alternative implementation options for usage of Call Log or SMS
>   permissions.
>
> Update your app or submit a Permissions Declaration Form.
>
> Option 1) If your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS
>   permissions: Make appropriate changes to your app by removing the
>   specified permissions from your app's manifest or migrating to an
>   available alternative implementation by January 9, 2019.
>
> Option 2) If your app is a default handler or you believe your app
>   qualifies for an exception: Please submit a request via the
>   Permissions Declaration Form. You do not need to have implemented APK
>   changes in order to submit a form. Declaration Forms received by
>   January 9, 2019 may be eligible for additional time to make changes to
>   bring their app(s) into compliance. If you have recently submitted a
>   Permissions Declaration Form, we are in the process of reviewing your
>   information and will respond to your application.
>
> Make sure that your app is otherwise compliant with all other
>   Developer Program Policies to prevent your app from being removed.
>
> Alternatively, you can choose to unpublish the app.
>
> Our Developer Program Policies are designed to provide a safe and
>   secure experience for our users while also giving developers the tools
>   they need to succeed. That is why we will remove apps that violate our
>   policies. In cases of repeated or serious violations of our policies,
>   we may also terminate your developer account and any related developer
>   accounts.
>
> We appreciate your willingness to partner with us as we make these
>   improvements to better protect users.
>
> Affected apps
>
> Affected apps and permissions are listed below, up to 20; if you have
>   additional apps, please ensure that they are also compliant with the
>   Permissions policy.

Comment: Have you got the solution for this problem?

Comment: No, I submitted for the review but they rejected, so I decided to republish without auto detect OTP.

Comment: Do any of the following disallowed use cases apply to your app’s core functionality request for Call Log or SMS permissions? ..... What is mean by disallowed use cases? in Google Play Permissions Declaration Form.

Comment: Should I remove READ_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS permission?  I  am not available to upload my apk ! What should I do?

Comment: Did you submitted for review?? if yes and they rejected then, If your app doesn't have the core functionality for Autodetect Sms either you remove READ_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS and republish or use the below solutions

Comment: What if my app dont use sms and call log permission then what should i fill in my declaration form ??and does dependency uses this kind of permissions ?

Comment: @MazRoid If your app not needs Sms and call log, remove the permissions from manifest and republish the app, no need to submit the review.
If dependency uses also you have to do the same

Comment: @Aabauser I had already removed from my App manifest but every-time i am adding an update on PlayStore it asks me to fill that form! how can get knowledge about dependency is using that permissions or not ?

Comment: I am using READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE for getting some files in my app , will google remove my app aswell ?

Comment: @John No, Currently restrictions on RECEIVE_SMS, READ_SMS, SEND_SMS and call logs these permissions only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app not using those permissions and the third-party library using some kind of those permission use below code for avoiding those permissions. **it may affect those library smooth functioning**

```
 <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"
        tools:node="remove" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"
        tools:node="remove" />
```

or else you can use alternate methods in the answers, example

[SMS Retriever Api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)

Answer (score 7):

this one is also a solution.. without submitting form we have another solution .. for this we need to genarate app id..

[SMS Retriever Api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview)

Answer (score 5):

This is really new headache for developers
While updating my app to play store with new version code i can't found to fill permission declaration form.
I'm not using SMS and call log permissions any more but still i can't able to update my app.

How I solve this problem hope it helps some one

- First check if you have any alpha,beta or any other active testing tracks.
- If you have then go to artifact library and see how many active artifacts you have.
- Go through permissions of each of them if you find the sms or call log permission in any of them then that means you found the problem.
- Deactivated the track if you can.
- If you can't able to deactivate them create an APK with those permission and upload it to the track which contain APK with those permission previously in the artifact library.
- Then you will see the permission declaration form fill that form choose no when it asked did your app follow Google play store permission policy then roll out your application.
- Then do same for all the active tracks without permission and this time you can choose Yes in declaration form and choose the option for which you use those permission previously I'm using for OTP verification so I choose that one.
- After updating these all tracks you need to promote your app to production one by one with increasing order of version code at last only one active artifact track, only production and now you can update in that track only.

Hope it help some one.......

Answer (score 1):

Its not like that you are thinking about. Go to this [link](https://www.google.com/appserve/mkt/p/ABMBUQOLM85UKtRHgtCNj9Ft0yUFY_rl_qxhEQt_G9ep_eLGB_Ryq9AcKp8HlfHZ7IhAZzX_e7eRXKQMYXazAsbMsFYXEYg14blCEHnLoB1xbwXk2X20LpWuQdK9f39sWYHi3JT1o7bb1LxgIyWIA7eksTXtGACiXKh4QzQkHRF-oJtdoNCFGQ)
and fill up and submit the from. If you app's default function is to show SMS inbox or just OTP account verification, then they will not remove your app.

Answer (score 1):

Google is no more allowing more apps with SMS permission due to security and privacy issue. So if you need Phone No verification then

[Firebase Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui) is the best option. It's almost free

Limit:Verification code SMS messages    50 messages/IP address/minute, 500 messages/IP address/hour

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth

Answer (score 1):

According to google "You may only request permissions that are necessary to implement critical current features or services in your application. You may not use permissions that give access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes".

[Click Here To Read Official Google Permission Doc](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/permissions/)

If your app need to read sms for SMS-based user verification / OTP verification please use [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/overview) which does not needed any sms permission and your app can still read SMS for OTP verification.