# I am Getting this Warning When I upload My App To Playstore

Tags: android

This app does not meet the Google Play permissions policy relating to the use of SMS or CALL_LOG. You must fix this before March 9. 2019 or your app will be removed from Google Play. Note: if you have recently made a change, it can take up to 12 hours to update this message.

This is the error which i get at my play store console.

Please give me the suggestion to resolve this case

Comment: Do you provide a privacy policy website?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Permissions policy that will limit which apps are allowed to request Call Log and SMS permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405467/permissions-policy-that-will-limit-which-apps-are-allowed-to-request-call-log-an)

Answer (score 0):

Google has recently updated their SMS and CALL_LOG related permissions. You can find about the changes [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/10/providing-safe-and-secure-experience.html).

If your app does not require access to Call Log or SMS permissions: Remove the specified permissions from your app's manifest, or migrate to an [alternative implementation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9047303). If you require additional time to remove permissions or migrate to an alternative option, submit a [Permissions Declaration Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfCnRaa4b1VuHhE4gVekWJc_V0Zt4XiTlsKsTipTlPg5ECA7Q/closedform) to request an extension until March 9, 2019.

Comment: My app doesn't do sms reading, but still I got the warning. What permissions do I have to remove from my manifest? I do not see anything like SMS or CALL_LOG in my manifest file.

Comment: it is possible that any third party library that you are using in your app is using any SMS or CALL_LOG permissions. Check the merged manifest of your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the permission you can submit a request to Google Play allowing you to use that particular permission, you will be prompted to fill in a form if you have a new *"Use Case"* it will take up to 2 business days to be reviewed.

> I submitted through Developer Console in Release Management -> App Releases -> CREATE RELEASE