# Google play: about the Permissions Declaration Form

Tags: android, google-play

Google recently announced an update to their Google Play Developer policy, essentially related to SMS and Call Logs.

Previously, my app requires the sms/call related permissions, which is declared in the AndroidManifest, but that was about six month ago. Later, I just removed all the sms and call (also contacts) permissions.

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_NUMBERS" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ANSWER_PHONE_CALLS" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" tools:node="remove" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" tools:node="remove" />
> ```

But when submitting the new App, I still need to fill the Permissions Declaration Form, it's mandatory. This is really confusing. My AndroidManifest does not contain the listed 6 permissions anymore. How to resolve this? It's not appropriate selecting any sms/call handler because my app does not require this anymore.
[image]

Comment: any resolution on this ?

Comment: yes, we found that there exists an old apk in the alpha track....we uploaded a new apk. Then, the Form disappears. You can refer this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405467/permissions-policy-that-will-limit-which-apps-are-allowed-to-request-call-log-an. Ankitraj dwivedi gave me the solution

Comment: Had the same problem. Thank you mate @mianlaoshu , you saved my life.