# How to handle sms with more than 160 characters like 250 characters in broadcast receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver, smsmanager

How can i handle multipart sms in broadcast receiver and store it in one string before start operation on it like i want to store multipart sms in one string and then split it with different delimiter and then get status codes from it i have 1 sms with 250 characters . i tried with below code but not working i tested it on emulator kindly help me i also put code for receiving.

```
String mySmsText ;
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
             Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
             final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
             for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
              }
                 StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
                  if (messages.length > 0) {
                  for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                      content.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                        }
                    }
                   mySmsText = content.toString();
                  }    
            instance.t1.setText(mySmsText);
        }
   }
```

i tried to print msg but it display bad characters also overrides old one.

I'm sorry in first there is no problem with my code the problem is only with emulator on which i was tested. when i test it on real device it work well i'm sorry ...

Comment: I am not sure of what is your problem. It is to recreate mutlipart SMS on receive ? What is the current result ? I have that code at home, I will try to remember to check that in a few hours.

Comment: I tried to receive SMS which have 250 character but when I receive it it splits and on my text view it displays SMS by SMS . I want to join all that msgs and then display only 1 string

Comment: Long SMS are received in one intent, this is the content of your `SmsMessage[] messages`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469881/broadcastreceiver-for-multipart-sms)

Comment: I tried something same but not  getting right string may I wrong because I test it on emulator still I tried with that example and notify you about update thanks for your valuable answer

Comment: It may be done because the problem is with emulator but when i test it on real device it work well still i check for multiple times to final it. thanxs @AxelH for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i done it thanx **mr AxelH** for your answer

```
DataBaseHandler db;
        String mySmsText;
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            db = new DataBaseHandler(context);
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                if (messages.length > 0) {
                    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
                    for (SmsMessage sms : messages)
                        content.append(sms.getDisplayMessageBody());
                    mySmsText = content.toString();
                }
                db.update_sys_pwd(mySmsText);
                instance.t1.setText(mySmsText);
            }
        }
```

Comment: At least, explain what you have done, 'I see that you use getDisplayMessageBody()`, add some information about the why. If someone ends up here with the same problem, this could be useful.

Comment: the problem is with emulator and i don't store whole sms . and sms.getDisplayMessageBody() method returns sms body. which store in StringBuffer object after that is display text and i test it in real device.

Comment: Edit your answer with more information, don't tell me ;)